# EJB 3.0 Business Interfaces

Tags: java, interface, containers, ejb-3.0

Good Morning in my timezone.

I am preparing to the EJB certification exame, and i have a doubt regarding the business interfaces.In the book that i am reading says :

> If you want, you can apply the @Local, @Remote, or @WebService
>   annotation in the bean class without having to implement the business
>   interface

This means that if i code this :

```
@Remote(BidManager.class)
@Stateless
public class BidManagerBean {
...
}
```

The compiler (container) will generate the business interface for me ?
Thanks in advance
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the compiler/container will not generate the BidManager interface for you. You need to write the interface. Assuming BidManager has a method named someMethod(), that quote is saying you can do this:

```
@Stateless
@Local(BidManager.class)
public class BidManagerBean {
    public void someMethod() { ... }
}
```

...rather than needing to implement the interface:

```
@Stateless
public class BidManagerBean implements BidManager {
    public void someMethod() { ... }
}
```

When a BidManager proxy is created, the container will ensure that the someMethod will be proxied even though the bean doesn't actually implement the interface.